# Kurento media server error (GLib-CRITICAL)

Tags: webrtc, glib, kurento

KMS crashed with following error message:

```
(kurento-media-server:6421): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
^[[31;1mSegmentation fault^[[0m (thread ^[[33;1m140303257732864^[[0m, pid ^[[33;1m24975^[[0m)


GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_socket_send_message: assertion 'G_IS_SOCKET (socket)' failed
```

Enviroment:

```
Version: 6.6.1
Found modules:
    Module: 'core' version '6.6.1'
    Module: 'elements' version '6.6.1'
    Module: 'filters' version '6.6.1'
```

Server specs:

```
CPU: 2.4 Ghz
RAM: 30 Gb
```

There was 10-15 viewers and 4-6 presenters at this moment.

Hope this details will help to understand issue, thx.

Comment: @igracia maybe you can help? or it's better to create an issue on github?

Comment: Seems like the questioner should be directed to this software's bugtracker